# How to break tablenotes (page break) in longtable with threeparttablex?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable, threeparttablex

How can I break my `TableNotes` in `ThreePartTable` (it is a `landscape` table)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2.975cm, bottom=2.975cm, left=2.975cm, right=2.975cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item[a]\label{tn:a} \blindtext
\item[b]\label{tn:b} \blindtext
\item[c]\label{tn:c} Test.
\item[d]\label{tn:d} Test.
\item[e]\label{tn:e} Test.
\item[f]\label{tn:f} Test.
\item[g]\label{tn:g} \blindtext
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}{lcc}
\caption{A Test Table} \\
\toprule
First Column & Second Column & Third Column \\
\midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes \\
\endlastfoot
Test & Test & Test \\
Test & Test & Test \\
Test & Test & Test \\
Test & Test & Test
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}

\newpage
\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the notes exceed the margin (in the example, notes e, f, and g should be on a new page).

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Welcome! How do you want to break them exactly? The example you've given does not, I think, exceed a page, so it isn't clear what the context of your question is exactly. By the way, don't use `\it` in LaTeX. Is is 20+ years deprecated. Use `\itshape` or `\textit{}` instead.

Comment: OK, I edited the example: defined margins and added some tablenotes. I would like to break them so that everything is within the margins.

Comment: Actually, I think I missed the text in the notes before. Sorry about that. But I still wasn't sure what you meant by wanting to break them.

Comment: What do you mean by "break" inside the `tablenotes` environment: A page break, or a line break? Please advise.

Comment: A page break. The notes exceed the margin (in the example above, notes e, f, and g should be on a new page).

Comment: @Dan I don't think you can do that. As I understand the manual (I've not read the code), the notes are typeset in a special `\multicolumn...`. So they are a single cell and cannot be broken across pages. I am not sure why they don't all get moved to the next page, though.

Comment: @Dan You need an example which shows the problem in your question. Your example needs to reproduce the problem you want help with. Otherwise you end up with useless answers like mine which only solve a problem you don't want help with. (At best. Answers may obviously fail to solve any problem but there the blame falls on the answer rather than the question.) Remember: we only know what you tell us. People try to answer the question you ask. Although people sometimes manage it, you can't count on us answering the one you meant to ask instead ;).

Comment: More specifically, the notes are set inside a `\parbox` which is placed inside a `\makebox` which is set inside a `\multicolumn`. Any one of those would prevent the contents breaking across pages. (I did look at the code. I still don't know why it doesn't put a page break before the notes.)

Comment: OK, thanks. Is there like a second-best solution? For example, can I somehow manually put some of the notes (in the example notes e, f, and g) on a new page?

Comment: @Dan - By providing table-related footnotes that -- taken together -- are so voluminous as to require a page break, you may be mis-using the entire `longtable`and `threeparttablex` machinery. In general, footnotes work best if they're (a) short and (b) contain mainly ancillary information. If the information provided in the footnotes is truly so important as to require the footnotes to be quite voluminous, do examine carefully whether there's a better way than footnotes to convey the ancillary/supplemental information you believe you need to convey.